# Espresso Testing 'Process Crashed' immediately when using ProGuard

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-logcat

I've got a rather large project for which I've written a test suite. When running the tests on a build that is not minified, the tests run fine. Once I set `minifyEnabled` to `true` on the buildType I'm using, the tests immediately fail with the following message:

```
Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
Empty test suite.
```

No stacktrace, nothing in Logcat.

I've set the correct `testBuildType` param in my `build.gradle` file, and that's working as expected, and I'm specifying a test version of my proguard file using `testProguardFiles`

My question is two-fold. First, has anyone else experienced this and solved it, and second is there any way to get a more verbose output of the problem as oppose to simply 'process crashed`?

Comment: Are you using any third party libraries, Google Maps or Firebase?

Comment: @Barns firebase-core 11.8.0 and firebase-messaging 11.8.0, as well as dozens of other third-party libraries. About 40 lines of dependencies in total.

Comment: this might help, if not let me know :: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/145 Or this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497673/firebase-androidchat-release-build-error

Comment: @Barns No dice, unfortunately.